# Create a global variable for use in all templates

Tags: php, functions, users, globals

I used following code

```
function userinfo_global() {
    global $users_info;
    wp_get_current_user();
}
add_action( 'init', 'userinfo_global' );
```

in a file `users.php` , this file are call in inside `funtions.php`.

in template file I have `<?php echo $users_info->user_firstname; ?>` , but no working..

I want to do global `wp_get_current_user();`

You know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll also have to fill the variable, e.g.

```
function userinfo_global() {
    global $users_info;
    $users_info = wp_get_current_user();
}
add_action( 'init', 'userinfo_global' );
```

And you should then be able to use $users_info everywhere in global context. Keep in mind that some template pars (header.php, footer.php, those used via `get_template_part`) are not in global scope by default, so you'll have to use `global $users_info;` in those files before accessing the variable.

Answer (score 4):

`wp_get_current_user()` is already a global function predefined by WordPress. Since you'd have to add `global $users_info;` to your templates to make sure that you always have the global variable, you might just as well have `$users_info = wp_get_current_user();` in its place.